# Ajax request has session expired error when going through AzureFrontDoor proxy

Tags: php, laravel, azure, proxy

Now I'm using Azure Front Door as load balaner of my service. My service is hosted by Nginx and worked by laravel framework

Here is my structure.[service structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw9uc.png)
VMs are having their own domains like app1.pabit.tube, app2.pabit.tube, ...
And AFD has our first domain as 'app.pabit.tube' so users can access our service by 'app.pabit.tube'.

1. When entering our service directly by VM's domain(app1.-), there are no issues about session, authentication, ajax, query.
2. When entering our service by AFD domain(app.-), it comes to session expired error only for ajax requests not for other requests.
   [No error when normal requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3IhZ.png)
   [There is no XSRF-token when ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CnE7.png)
   [It comes to session expired(419)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpo26.png) [No error when direct accessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIWqb.png)
3. I've configured trustedhosts as same as below. It helps clearing session expired error when entering by AFD and requesting login.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts as Middleware;

class TrustHosts extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the host patterns that should be trusted.
     *
     * @return array<int, string|null>
     */
    public function hosts()
    {
        return [
                $this->allSubdomainsOfApplicationUrl(),
                '*.pabit.tube'
        ];
    }
}
```

But I got error when requesting ajax so I wonder that there is any other configs about ajax.

I wonder what I should check for.

Thank you.